# After adding ids and css with javascript, only text color is interpreted by Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm working on a small GreaseMonkey script that would color all visited links on all webpages and add a border to them.

I have finally settled on the following method: first each link is assigned a unique ID, then a CSS style for the ID is added to the head. It looks this way right now:

```
function colorLinks() {
    var as = $("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        var idName = "generated_link-" + i
        as[i].id = idName;

        var css = "<style type='text/css'> "
        + "a#" + idName + ":visited " 
        + " { color: red !important; background-color: red !important; } "
        + "</style>";
        $(css).appendTo("head");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(colorLinks, 2000)
});
```

I know it's not terribly efficient (I can end up with hundreds of duplicated styles), but right now I don't care for efficiency, I care for effectiveness and that I cannot get, because only the color style gets applied, but not background color nor border.

Funnily enough, when I add background in the Firefox inspector, for a `a` with background-color already defined, the style will be interpreted and the background will be of the proper color (no matter what is set using the inspector -- without the `!important` keyword).

Comment: The colour only gets applied to visited links because that's the only thing you're styling here. Unless I've missed something?

Comment: Yup, but what I meant was: *only* the color gets applied, not the background-color, nor border (the border isn't styled in the above code, but I tried it earlier to no avail).

Comment: Did the solution I offer solve this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define a background color for non-visited links:

```
a{color:black; background:white;}
a:visited{color:black; background:blue;}
```

Go to google.com then try this in Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/1phazdys/6/

If you remove the background color from `a` (the first style) you'll see the visited link also loses its background color.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags are inline elements. You need to set them to `display: inline-block;` (or likely less preferably, `display: block;`, which will make them occupy full-width by default) to apply borders or background colors.